# price filter Onresize function is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to develop a `price filter` in `magento 1.9`
and i have done this which is not working.

```
<div class="price_range_caption">

<span class="currency_from">Rs.</span><span id="price_range_fromprice" >1250</span><span id="price_range_toprice">6600</span><span class="currency_to">Rs.</span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var slider = create_price_slider(170, 0, 170, 1250, 6600,"price");
window.onresize = function() {


var url = window.location.href;
var pa = document.getElementById("price_range_fromprice").innerHTML;
var pb = document.getElementById("price_range_toprice").innerHTML;

window.location.assign(url+"&price="+pa+"-"+pb);


};


</script>
```

Url us generating ok i have tested it but ONRESIZE function is not working.
[image]

Comment: why are using the ONRESIZE function?

Comment: for price filter on left side bar i shared the picture

Comment: do you have any other technique for price filter just like i need.

Comment: use this slider it is easy to add your function  http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-create-price-range-slider-in-jquery-php-with-mysql_437.html

Comment: oka i am trying

Comment: are you doing theming or creating a custom module?

Comment: custom. in theming their is a price range in written form.

Comment: i will recommended add free extension for that

Comment: @QaisarSatti kindly help me with this problem
http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/112087/37202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are list the list of free layered navigation

https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ajax+layered+navigation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=magento+free+layered+navigation

if you want to create the custom i recommend this tutorial

http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-create-price-range-slider-in-jquery-php-with-mysql_437.html