# how to create a CRON job to update products inventory

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml, cron

I want to create a CRON job which updates my Magento products Inventory by matching `sku` and `product name` with the third party products inventory. third party is using `Sql server` and my Magento project is on `MySql`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to write a webservice which will get pass sku and get the qty for that product and use following code to update $qty at magento product.

The following code uses magento soap api to update qty of the product

```
<?php $client = new SoapClient('http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login($soapusername,$soappassword); // soap user name and password

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('product_category_id',4)->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);

foreach($products as $product)
{
    $quantity = write a funtion which will take the sku of the product and get the qty of that product
    $qty = array();
    if($qty > 0 ){
        $qty['qty'] = $quantity;
        $qty['is_in_stock'] = 1;
    }else{
        $qty['qty'] = 0;
        $qty['is_in_stock'] = 0;
    }
    $client->catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate($session,$product->getSku(),$qty);
}

?>
```

Note:- write the above code in cron.this is the code which will update stock of product in magento